# Progress Indication for RecurrenceTable

Tags: difference-equations, monitoring

I am trying to figure out how to implement progress indicator in RecurrenceTable.  I have a complicated code within the With function that contains recurrence table.  A simple code will suffice say,

```
ans = RecurrenceTable[{a[n+1] == 3a[n], a[1] == 7, a, {n, 1, 10}]
```

I tried the following,

```
ans=RecurrenceTable[{a[n+1]==3a[n], a[1]==7, a, {Dynamic[n],1,10}]
ans=RecurrenceTable[{a[n+1]==3a[n], a[1]==7, a, {ProgressIndicator[n],1,10}]
ans=RecurrenceTable[{a[n+1]==3a[n], a[1]==7, a, PrintTemporary[n],{n,1,10}]
Monitor[RecurrenceTable[{a[n+1]==3a[n], a[1]==7,a,{n,1,10}],ProgressIndicator[n]]
```

and all of them failed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think that `RecurrenceTable` exposes the value of the iterator `n` it is working on the way that `Table` does, so I am not sure that this is possible.